# The Cantor function is surjective and continuous

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that the Cantor function is surjective and continuous?

The part,
I think that the cantor function is monotonic and surjective, if I prove this, it is easy to prove that this implies continuity. The way to prove that is surjective, it's only via an algorithm, I don't know if this can be proved in a different way, more elegant. And the monotonicity I have no idea, I think that it's also via an algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: See Problems in real and complex analysis
 By Bernard R. Gelbaum, pages [17](http://books.google.com/books?id=v7_FiqY3FX0C&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [155](http://books.google.com/books?id=v7_FiqY3FX0C&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Comment (I don't have enough points to post a comment, sorry): A delta-epsilon proof is not too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the Cantor function.  Let $y\in[0,1]$.  Let $0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots$ be the binary expansion of $y$.  Let $x$ be the number whose ternary expansion is $0.(2d_1)(2d_2)(2d_3)\ldots\ {}$.  Then $f(x)=y$.  For numbers with non-unique binary expansions, one gets two ternary expansions that do *not* represent the same number; call them $x_1 < x_2$.  Then for all $x\in [x_1,x_2]$, $f(x)=y$.

As for continuity, if a weakly monotone function has a discontinuity, it is a *jump*, so then the function cannot be surjective.